# The Geppy String: Regex vs Iteration

Tags: strings, ruby, programming-challenge, comparative-review

> We'll say that a lowercase 'g' in a string is "happy" if there is another 'g' immediately to its left or right. Return true if all the g's in the given string are happy.
>
> ```
> gHappy("xxggxx") → true
> gHappy("xxgxx") → false
> gHappy("xxggyygxx") → false
> ```

I have written two functions to solve this problem, but I have some concerns:

- Of the one with Regex, I don't like all the special cases.
- Of the one with iteration, I don't like the weird helper method.

Both pass a fair number of tests and work correctly. Which one is better?

**regex_geppy.rb**

```
def geppy(string)
  return true if ! string.include?('g')
  return false if [0, 1].include?(string.length)
  return false if string.length == 2 && string != 'gg'
  return (not string.match("[^g]g[^g]"))
end
```

**array_geppy.rb**

```
def non_wrap_get(array, index)
  index < 0 ? nil : array[index]
end

def geppy(string)
  string
    .chars
    .each_with_index
    .all? { |curr, i| 
      curr == 'g' ? 
        non_wrap_get(string, i - 1) == 'g'  || non_wrap_get(string, i + 1) == 'g' 
        : true
    }
end
```

**geppy_tests**

```
geppy("xxggxx") #=> true
geppy("xxgxx") #=> false
geppy("xxggyygxx") #=> false
geppy("g") #=> false
geppy("ag") #=> false
geppy("gg") #=> true
geppy("") #=> true
geppy("ab") #=> true
geppy("aaaa") #=> true
geppy('g'*1000) #=> true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@200_success already showed a compact solution using regular expressions. As for the "array-solution", I think you missed the abstraction [Enumerable#chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk):

```
def g_happy(s)
  s.chars.chunk { |c| c }.all? { |c, cs| c == "g" ? cs.size > 1 : true } 
end
```

Or `.all? { |c, cs| cs != ["g"] }`, whatever feels more declarative to you.

Comment: Error: `undefined method "itself" for string` which version are you using?

Comment: >= 2.2.0. Changed to a more portable block.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are the right tool to use for this kind of test.  However, if you are going to use a regular expression to find lonely `g` characters, then you should use negative lookbehind and lookahead assertions instead of the negated character class `[^g]`.

```
def geppy(str)
  !/(?<!g)g(?!g)/.match(str)
end
```